# Comparing values in Excel between YTD Monthly reports

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I am extracting Year To Date monthly reports on tickets and their statuses.

I have a report for Apri:

`ID` `Status`
`123` `Open`
`124` `Closed`

and another report in May:

`ID` `Status`
`123` `Closed`
`124` `Closed`
`125` `Open`

I need to find out how many tickets have closed since April based on the May report. So in this case only one ticket -> 123. 124 was already closed in April so I am not counting it as closed in May, although it will be present in May's report. I am basically looking for changes of statuses between the two reports.

I am obviously working with a larger amount of data. This is a regular report that I should extract so I am also looking into automation possibilities(e.g. macro or VBA).

Comment: Where is the April report? Is it stored in the same workbook? What have you tried? What do you mean by "macro or VBA"? Macros are written with VBA.

Comment: April and May reports are in different files altogether. They are not in the same workbook. I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I was thinking of a combination of VLOOKUPS and IF's but I can't figure it out. My mistake about macros or VBA, I meant macros and VBA. I don't know much VBA as a language but if there is a way of making this through Excel functions then I can automate it using macro recorder which is very friendly and visual.

Comment: This sounds like rather bad information architecture. Every month, the macro would have to look in a different file. As an alternative, you could arrange for the source data to capture the date a status was changed. If the source data is in Excel, that will be very easy. Then you can build reports by simply counting the statuses with a date stamp in that month.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that a solution the following will do.

Sheet April

[image: Sheet April]

Sheet May

[image: Sheet May]

Sheet May C2 (April Status) write formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;April!$A$2:$B$3;2;FALSE));"")
```

And D2 write

```
=IF(AND(C2="Open";B2="Closed");1;0)
```

I believe will want to Sum column D

Comment: Your c2 formula could sligthly be improved with iferror() instead of if(iserror(...)

Comment: IFERROR() takes two parameters. However, the only parameter to me back in the area and need a formula that returns TRUE or FALSE value. For him ISERROR () used.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. I was thinking at =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;April!$A$2:$B$3;2;FALSE);"") it is more or less the same formula, but it is shorter.

Comment: Not the same. IFERROR () just returns an error value when. What will be result not error.

Comment: IFERROR Returns a value you specify if a formula evaluates to an error; otherwise, returns the result of the formula.

Syntax

IFERROR(value,value_if_error)

Comment: Okay, it was now. I did not know that not error the result of the formula. Thanks for your information.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29470/discussion-between-momobo-and-sakir-sen)